# How I make a portable version of Bitcoin for Ubuntu?

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, bitcoin-core, ubuntu

I want to create a bitcoin wallet executable file in Ubuntu with all its dependencies. So when use that file from some other system it will work perfectly.

How I make a portable version of Bitcoin for Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you mean a portable installation of the Bitcoin wallet, so that it can be used from e.g. a usb stick?

Comment: No, I want to create a wallet through release process from my source code, so I can use that executable file on other system.

Comment: What other system? Windows? Another computer with linux? Please be more specific.

Comment: Yes, Another Computer is also a linux, same executable run on one linux, two linux machine, and so on. I don't want to make all dependencies installed and compile source code again and again on other computer. the same executable file [which i was build earlier] do all the task.

Comment: I believe that one would call this a "portable installation" ;)

Comment: OK, So how I can achieve that...

Comment: Docker is a server-side tool to distribute static, self-contained, portable, applications https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-bitcoind

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Given the tags, I think the asker is looking for one that works on bitcoin-qt too.